# Why can't I use a table's alias and its original name in the same query when two tables are joined?

Tags: sql, sqlite, alias

Assume there are two tables created by:

```
CREATE TABLE emp
(
EMPNO int,
EMPNAME varchar(255),
JOB varchar(255),
DEPTNO int
);

CREATE TABLE dept
(
LOC varchar(255),
DEPTNO int
);
```

I want to find out what dept has no employ. I use a left join like this:

```
select dept.* 
from dept  
left join emp 
 on (dept.deptno=emp.deptno) 
where emp.empno is null;
```

But if I use an alias for dept or emp, then I can only use alias and cannot use the original table name. For instance:

```
select dept.* 
from dept as d 
left join emp 
 on (dept.deptno=emp.deptno) 
where emp.empno is null;
```

I get an error "no such table: dept" from sqlite.

If I run operations on one table, I can use alias and the original table name in the same query.

Anybody know why?

Comment: You are probably mistaken: you can't use the original name when you have assigned a different alias [even if you are querying a single table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/98a82/1). In any event, the behaviour you are observing is according to SQL standard, as far as I know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you assign an alias to a table, that's its new name during the query - the original name is then not available.

The "why" is due to the SQL standard. If you're looking for an explanation of why would it have been specified to work that way, the main reason I can think of is if you join a table to itself, you need to alias at least one reference to distinguish them, but if you were allowed to also use the original name, it would be ambiguous as it could refer to either reference.

Also, if you want to use the original name, don't assign an alias

Comment: "*Once you assign an alias to a table, that's its new name during the query - the original name is then not available.*" -- Can you please provide the source of this information?

Comment: @shynur https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM says *The alias becomes the new name of the table reference so far as the current query is concerned — it is not allowed to refer to the table by the original name elsewhere in the query*

Comment: Thanks. It would be better if the source was written into the answer, as comments are easily ignored. I am using PostgreSQL, and this is indeed the default behavior for PostgreSQL. But is this an ISO SQL behavior?

Comment: @shynur yes, it's in the SQL standard (I just found a ref quickly). As per my answer, if you think about it it *must* work this way otherwise a table could not be joined to itself. You should do your own research - the info is all out there only a few searches away.